# NodeJS Testing Failed Authorization

Tags: node.js, testing

I have a test suite set up that runs all my tests. While testing one particular model, I ran the test dedicated to that one model. Worked through all the bugs...+1

[Successfull Tests when run by file alone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZHn8.png)

My structure is:

server-test
--NonAuth
--Auth
----profile.test.js
--user.test.js

When I run the main test script in package.json:

`export NODE_ENV=test && mocha --recursive server-tests/**/* --timeout 5000`

Everything is found but I am getting a

```
Error: expected 200 "OK", got 401 "Unauthorized"
```

[Link to error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pk6A.png)
[Link to next error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuS0r.png)

When it begins the test 'Auth/profile.test.js' throws the above error.

Is there a problem with file structure?

Comment: The issue is with authorization. You need to pass auth header to the api call

Comment: Its passed. I am sorry. I didn't include any code. I will in a bit. Been rushed with other projects...